# Change icons for a specific file type in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, files, icons, themes

I want to change the icons for a specific file type (*.py to be specific) on Ubuntu 18.04.

What's the simplest way to do it?

I'm using Ubuntu-mono-Dark as the icon theme.

Comment: I don't think so. It is talking about creating mime types for applications whereas `py` is a text file type.

Comment: there are a lot of mime types for text file, taking a look at the  `/etc/mime.types` file will convince you... that the referred answer is the good one